# How does collection sampling affect the "live" stats for Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

We've noticed lately that as our site is growing, our data in Google Analytics is getting less reliable.

One of the places we've noticed this most strongly is on the "Realtime Dashboard".

When we were getting 30k users per day, it would show about 500-600 people on line at a time. Now that we are hitting 50k users per day, it's showing 200-300 people on line at a time.

(Other custom metrics from within our product show that the user behavior hasn't changed much; if anything, users are currently spending longer on the site than ever!)

The daily totals in analytics are still rising, so it's not like it's just missing the hits or something... Does anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that there is probably a difference in interpretation of what constitutes a user being on line.

How do you determine if the user is on line?

Unless there is an explicit login/logout tracking, is it possible that it assumes that a user has gone if there is no user generated event or a request from the browser within an interval of X seconds?

If that is the case then it may be worth while adding a hidden iframe with some Javascript code that keeps sending a request every t seconds.

Comment: Yeah, we're already sending a 'heartbeat' every minute for this among other reasons. However, the bigger concern is why there was a sudden *change* in the number of reported users, which doesn't match that actual number of users.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare instant measures of unique, concurrent users to different time-slices of unique users.

For example, you could have a small number of concurrent unique users (say 10) and a much higher daily unique users number like 1000, because 1000 different people were there over the course of the day, but only 10 at any given time.  The number of concurrent users isn't correlated to the total daily uniques, the distribution over the course of the day may be uneven and it's almost apples and oranges.

This is the same way that monthly unique and daily uniques can't be combined, but average daily uniques are a lower bound for monthly uniques.